# blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload - multiple select on Ipad (ios7) app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, cordova

I am using the Basic plugin, implementing my own preview within the "add" callback.
This works fine on web browser.
Using the same code with phonegap in Ipad app:
When I select multiple files. I first get only one image (the add is triggers only once)
the next time I select multiple files I get some of the previous images I selected. and so on...

Comment: I see no question/issue explanation here.

Comment: The problem is on the Ipad, When I multi selelct images on the Ipad the add callback is triggers only once with only one image

Comment: I set
singleFileUploads: false

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I set the option:
 singleFileUploads: false
Now I get all the selected file in the "add" callback